# Request name not being recognized for update method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel is not returning the 'as' name of a specific request.

The below two examples show the output for each case (one works fine, the other does not)

The route is defined as a "resource", shows up in the route list as "companies.update" and all of the other routes work fine (except for update). Why is the update request not returning the route name?

```
{!! Form::model($company, ['route' => ['companies.update', $company->id], 'method' => 'patch', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
    @include('companies.form')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

[image: Nanana]
("update" does not return the name)

[image: Nanana]
(every other route name works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `php artisan route:list` again.
There is two entries for update. One for PUT and one for PATCH.

Maybe use the method PUT to see if it shows up (but both should work when you look at the HTML).

Comment: Great that worked! (changed method to put for an update and post for a create!)